# When is $ARGV present?

Tags: ruby

On my local machine, when running `rake assets:precompile`, `$ARGV` is present in both MRI and JRuby. In my deployment environment, it's not. This blew my mind, but then I realized that `ARGV` is present and is more standard.

Why is `$ARGV` set to `ARGV` when I run `rake assets:precompile` locally?

Comment: How are you detecting `$ARGV` is present?

Answer (score 2):

Use `ARGV`. It's a standard constant defined as part of [Object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html).

Here's a bit of the documentation from "The Ruby Programming Language":

> 10.2.2 Top-Level Constants
>
> When the Ruby interpreter starts, the following top-level constants are defined (in addition to the modules and classes listed previously). A module that defines a constant by the same name can still access these top-level constants by explicitly prefixing them with ::. You can list the top-level constants in your implementation with:
>
> ```
> ruby -e 'puts Module.constants.sort.reject{|x| eval(x.to_s).is_a? Module}'
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ARGV
>   An array containing the arguments specified on the command line. A synonym for $*.

I don't have jRuby so I can't comment on it, but I can't get MRI to define anything for `$ARGV` in several versions I've tried.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's not what I asked... :)

Comment: $ARGV is NOT present in Ruby. So, there's your answer. It might be created as an artifact in IRB or another gem, which is easily done, but don't rely on it.

Comment: `$ARGV` is a relic from Perl that shouldn't be used even if it was there.

Comment: yep, i know `ARGV` is standard and always present. see my clarified question above.